# MS Access - Connection fails on load, causes app to not respond

Tags: ms-access

I have an issue.  I have an Access Project (currently in access 2007), and the project connection properties are set to point to a hosted SQL database on our network.  Unfortunately we had to move the databasem and now I have to change the connection properties as well.

However, when I open the adp file, the first thing it does is try to connect to the old database.  I never get prompted or anything, the screen just sits there, and the title bar eventually indicates "not responding".

Anyone know how I can get to the connection properties, since Access never gives me a chance to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried keeping the shift key held down while the database is opening to prevent any start-up forms or macros from running? If that does not help, you can [change all the connections from VBScript](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Using_VBScript_to_Change_Link_Datasource).